# Getting around "Table per Concrete Class" in Hibernate inheritance mapping strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

In my java I have a generic class (could be abstract or non-abstract either way, but does NOT map to a table in the database). It has one or more variables that are common to every class. Example:

```
public class GenericThing {
    private Date createDate;
    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }
    public void setCreateDate(Date dt) {
        createDate = dt;
    }
}
```

This is useful because literally every table in the database has the column CREATE_DATE.

In this case the right inheritance strategy to use in Hibernate is "table per concrete class". But, this is "bad", they say, because each table requires that identical column and if you change that column name (CREATE_DATE) you have to change every table's column name. Well, obviously this is true, but what is the alternative? Obviously I do want every table in the database to store the Create Date, but I don't want every object in the entire database to be in one table, so that precludes (as far as I know) all the other mapping strategies, right?

Answer (score 1):

Actually for your usecase, nothing wrong in using `Table per concrete class` strategy

The problem you are trying to solve is not creating any redundancy at schema level(when tables are created). Even if we do the entity modelling in reverse mode, this is fine. In-fact, create_date is specific to each row for every table.

`Table per concrete class` is not recommended only when you are dealing normal inheritance for example User -> Customer -> Supplier where each extended class is a kind of parent class and the specific extra attributes added in the sub class need not be duplicated in the all the tables (Join Table strategy is recommended for such cases)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with *[table pet subclass](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass)* polymorphism? The parent table contains the commom columns, child tables the specifics.

Comment: table per subclass seems to assume that the parent class will be in the database. But as you can see in my example, the parent class is not an actual db object. It is an abstract class that contains a couple of fields that will be common to all concrete classes. It doesn't map to any particular table.

Comment: I suppose I could change the structure of the database to make it hold the parent class in a table. But wouldn't that require inner join every single time we want to access the create date of any item ever made?

Comment: Now you're confusing me. You don't want to have the same column repeated in each table, you do not want to hold the entire hierarchy in the same table and you do not want do keep common columns separately and do joins? So what exactly do you expect? At any rate, read https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html, and choose your option.